# Сортировка одного массива вместе с другим

Tags: actionscript-3, массивы, сортировка

Уже 20 минут сижу и думаю, как это реализовать, но ничего не приходит в голову.
Мне необходимо в AS3 отсортировать первый массив:

```
    Массив: 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0
```

вместе со вторым массивом:

```
    Массив: 125, 131, 137, 143, 149, 155
```

Так, чтобы первый ключи совпадали. Простой пример, что должно получится при их сортировании:

```
    Массив (1): 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0
    Массив (2): 137, 143, 149, 155, 125, 131
```

Говоря по другому, мы сортируем первый массив, но ключи по нему должны совпадать со вторым, к примеру третьем число в изначальном первом массиве было 2 и изначальным первым числом во втором массиве было 137, значит после сортировки они оба должны оказаться первыми.

Отсортировать каждый массив можно с помощью Array.sort(), а вот как второй подогнать сортировкой к первому не могу понять.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы создал новый массив пар, поставив в соответствие числам массива 2 ключи массива 1. И затем, сортировал бы пары по ключам.

Answer (score 2):

Ну Array.sort() тут вряд ли получится использовать. Как вариант - сортировать вручную любым удобным методом сортировки первый массив и, когда меняются местами в нём элементы, менять элементы на соответствующих позициях и во втором массиве.